Are questions migrated to other sites included when calculating a question ban?
If a user gets question banned after asking a new question but that question then gets migrated to another site, is the question still taken into account when calculating whether the user has a question ban?
I remember that I asked a question on an SE site and I immediately reached the limit - it didn't matter if it was upvoted/answered. In my memory, the first reactions were positive including a couple of upvotes, maybe even an answer. The question then got migrated and the "ban" was immediately lifted (as opposed to having to wait for a couple of months for it).
The Question ban FAQ states:

Additionally, for question bans, the fact that a question is deleted counts against you, if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question.

Migrated questions are deleted - does this count against the user? My memory of being unbanned seems to indicate it does not but it's not clear.
Edit trying to make my point clear
I am happy that someone tried to improve the question but the question was not limited to a question ban it included badges too. And it certainly wasn't restricted to a post-ban situation. Another similar situation is when the question is migrated before the question ban (if any happens). Let's say the person has N questions before the "ban" if some N-Xth question get's migrated before even the Nth question is asked does the N-Xth question still count against?
The migrated question normally counts as a closed question and there is a new question on the recepient.
I had originally asked a different question that was considered a duplicate (I did so especially because this question already has an accepted answer). But it seems that the question community considers it covers the issue below

I understand that the migrated question normally counts as a closed
question and there is a new question on the recepient. When the
migration is rejected is there a stub left on the previous destination
that counts as a closed question? Are there 2 question (a deleted stub
and a version migrated back) in the site that the question was
originally asked (the original origin)?

How exactly can a wrongful (it wasn't off topic in the origin site and the author didn't ask for it) migration be "corrected" (not just having the question in the Origin site but also not counting as a closed question in the destination site)?

AFAIK migrated questions start like a new question at the SE site they were migrated to. So any reputation loss that could contribute for a question ban at the originally posted site should be regained, and not count for it. Not sure what about flags received though.

The question ban algorithm is not public so you won't get an answer to anything about how the ban works. If you remove any mention of how the question ban works is there anything left of this question?

@πάνταῥεῖ I am asking about the "donor" site not the "recipient". I am asking about the site it was migrated away from. How does it count there?

@RobertLongson I didn't ask how the question ban algorithm works (I am not interested in the entire algorithm but the definition of a variable in it). I have seen when I ask question that my questions have been poorly received and the site no longer accepts questions or that some questions have been poorly received so I should take care because more poorly received question may inhibit me from asking further questions (it doesn't care if it was actually poorly received it just counts them against me). If the question is unacceptable we are left with "Does poorly received include migrated away"

Honestly, as someone who generally knows how a Q-ban works more than most, I can't honestly say that I know the answer to whether or not migrated questions are considered in the algorithm. I've tried to clean up the question somewhat - hopefully it still covers what you're trying to say.

You won't get any answers about any aspect of how question bans work beyond what it says in the FAQ

@RobertLongson While specifics of the ban aren't public, whether or not something impacts the ban and how it does (positively or negatively) is public information. For example, the fact that if a question is deleted more than 30 days after being asked then it doesn't count as deleted for the purposes of the ban is public. This question is asking purely about said public information.

Why wouldn't migrated questions be counted for the question ban? That the question was migrated still indicates that the user is not asking good questions for that site. The question ban exists to protect the site and other users from users who repeatedly post questions which are not well received (i.e., who expend the site's limited curation resources without lasting benefit to that site). A migrated question is, by definition, not well received on the original site. Why should the system not count such a question as one that wasn't well received?

@Makyen To add context, the author had one of their questions migrated by a moderator even though it wasn't a bad fit for the site it was asked on because they believed it would be a better fit for another site, despite that migration going explicitly against the guidance that migrations are reserved for cases where the question is a bad fit for its origin site. Because of that experience, the author may be under the impression that your definition isn't the case.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I don't see how that context matters for the question that's actually asked here. It does matter for how the user feels, and how they feel is something we care about as humans, but that's not the question which was asked. In addition, that context isn't anywhere in the question, in any revision, nor should it be in the question, because, again, that's not what the question is asking about.

@Makyen Supposedly the question covers this issue too (since the other question was considered a duplicate). A migration doesn't indicate that someone is not asking good questions. Some times there is heavy handed (unwarranted) moderation

Remember that migration is a form of closure. When a question is migrated, it is converted to a stub status and is closed and locked on the origin site, and a new copy of the question is posted on the destination site with some of its data (answers, score if not negative, original posting time, etc.) imported.
The migration stub, i.e., the original copy of your question on the origin site, continues to affect your standing there. Votes on that question cast before migration as well as the fact that your question is closed do impact your ban status. However, while as you noted the fact that your question is deleted negatively impacts your ban status, this fact is ignored if your question is deleted more than 30 days after it is asked. Migration stubs are automatically deleted 30 days after migration by a script that runs every week, so as long as your stub is deleted by this script, the fact that it's deleted will not impact your ban status.
As to why you noticed yourself being immediately banned after posting one question, that's because the system allows banned users to post one question every six months, but doesn't inform such users that they are still banned. As to why you saw the ban immediately lifted after your question got migrated, that's probably a coincidence - it's likely you received one or more upvotes, one or more downvotes were removed, or one of your closed questions got reopened or questions deleted within 30 days of being asked got undeleted. As I noted earlier, that a question gets migrated does negatively impact your site standing as it's considered a form of closure, which does.

What happens before the question ban? If one has more than a couple of question to ask before a question ban. Does a migrated question count as a "poorly received question". How is a poorly received question even defined?

@GeorgeNtoulos Before the question ban you are notified that your previous questions have been poorly received and that if you continue you risk being banned. A poorly received question is one that scores at or below 0.

@RobertLongson "A poorly received question is one that scores at or below 0." Does a question with neither up- nor downvotes count as "poorly received"?

@Velvet it does, yes. That's to prevent people from asking lots and lots of questions that nobody cares about.

I understand that the migrated question normally counts as a closed question and there is a new question on the recepient. When the migration is rejected is there a stub left on the previous destination that counts as a closed question? Are there 2 question (a deleted stub and a version migrated back) in the site that the question was originally asked (the original origin)? How exactly can a wrongful migration be "corrected" (not just having the question in the Origin site but also not counting as a closed question in the destination site)?

@RobertLongson So that is subjective (if people care about it) that is no longer following the Tour or guidelines

@GeorgeNtoulos You can request for the destination post to be dissociated from your account.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog What about the stub (closed and deleted) that is left in the origin?

@GeorgeNtoulos Note that if staff determine you're using dissociation as a means of evading question blocks, they will suspend your account.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog What is dissociation used for? I was wrongfully associated a question I din't ask (nor ask for it's migration). A ban (2 bans actually 1 in each site) already occured. There is a stub closed and deleted in Biology that while okay someone decided that it was better in Medicine.

@GeorgeNtoulos It is to satisfy a legal requirement of the CC BY-SA license, that those hosting such content have to remove one's name from their content if the author requests it. If you do make a request, then they have to honor it as a legal requirement, but they can take additional actions such as suspending users who abuse it.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Why would it be an abuse when I was associated a question I didn't ask in any way (wrongful migration).

@GeorgeNtoulos You could make your case for why you aren't abusing the system in your dissociation request (e.g., a migration that went explicitly against the Meta.SE FAQ guidelines). Staff handling the request will take those into account.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Which question would be dissociated from my account? The closed/deleted stub? The (+3) unanswered question in the destination? Both? What would be the consequences in the Q bans in these sites?
